# Collision detection in Java/Android

Tags: android

I want to check collision detection in a game (the code is below). I have a game class in which I am drawing bitmaps, making touch events and make an array list for moving a vehicle. In the vehicle class, I'm taking its getter setter bitmaps and the same in the frog class as vehicle.

I have a frog which is moving in all four directions. The vehicle is moving horizontally. Now if a frog touches a vehicle it should collide with it. What should I do to check collision by measuring height and width?

My code is:

For class `Game`:

```
    public class Game extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback  {
        private Frog frog;
        private FrogControl fg;
        private FrogControlY fg1;
        private MainThread thread;
        //private Vehicle vh;

        ImageView imgview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview);
        ImageView imageArr[] = new ImageView[20];
        int id[] = {R.drawable.audi_r8,    R.drawable.bike, R.drawable.bus, R.drawable.car,
                    R.drawable.chrysler, R.drawable.cruise_bike};

        ArrayList<Vehicle> vh = new ArrayList<Vehicle>();
        ArrayList<VehicleReverse> vhs = new ArrayList<VehicleReverse>();

        public Game(Context context) {
            super(context);
                getHolder().addCallback(this);
                frog= new Frog(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.frog),100,400);
                fg= new FrogControl(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.arrow),250,400);
                fg1=new FrogControlY(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.arrow),0,400);
                int noOfCar=(int)Math.random()*5;
                int totalCar=3+noOfCar;
                for(int j=0;j<totalCar; j++){
                    int y=(int)(Math.random()*3);
                    int[] LaneSelection  = {50,150,250};
                    int yValue=LaneSelection[y];
                    int x=0;
                    vh.add(new Vehicle(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), id[y]),x,yValue));
                }

                for(int k=totalCar-1; k>0; k--){
                    int y=(int)(Math.random()*3);
                    int[] LaneSelection  = {100,200,300};
                    int yValue=LaneSelection[y];
                    int x=300;
                    vhs.add(new VehicleReverse(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), id[y]),x,yValue));
                }
                thread=new MainThread(getHolder(),this);
                setFocusable(true);
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
                                       int height) {
                // TODO Nothing
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                thread.setRunning(true);
                thread.start();
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                boolean retry=true;
                thread.setRunning(false);
                while(retry){
                    try{
                        thread.join();
                        retry=false;
                    }catch(Exception e){

                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
                if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                //    vh.carmove();
                    fg.handleAction((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY());
                    fg1.handleActionY((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY());
                    if(fg.isTouched()){
                        //fg1.setTouchedY(false);
                        if((int)event.getX()<(250+(fg.getX()/2))&& (frog.getX()>0)){
                            frog.frogShiftLeft();
                        //    fg1.setTouchedY(true);
                        }
                        if((int)event.getX()>=(250+(fg.getX()/2))&&(frog.getX()<300)){
                            frog.frogShiftRight();
                        }
                }
                    if(fg1.isTouched()){
                        //fg.setTouched(false);
                        if((int)event.getY()<(380+(fg1.getY()/2))&& (frog.getY()>0)&&((int)event.getX()<100)){
                            frog.frogShiftUp();
                        //    fg.setTouched(true);
                        }
                        if((int)event.getY()>=(380+(fg1.getY()/2))&&(frog.getY()<400)&&((int)event.getX()<100)){
                            frog.frogShiftDown();
                        }
                    }
                }

                if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){}

                if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                    if(frog.isTouched()){
                        frog.setTouched(false);
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }

            public void render(Canvas canvas){
                canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
                fg.draw(canvas);
                fg1.draw(canvas);
                frog.draw(canvas);
                for(int j=0;j<vh.size();j++){
                //for(int j=vh.size()-1; j>0; j--){
                    Vehicle o=vh.get(j);
                    o.draw(canvas);
                }
                for(int k=vhs.size()-1; k>0; k--){
                    VehicleReverse v=vhs.get(k);
                    v.draw(canvas);
                }
            }
        }
```

For the Frog class:

```
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.Canvas;

    public class Frog {
        private Bitmap bmp;
        private int x;
        private int y;
        private boolean touched;

        public Frog(Bitmap bitmap,int x,int y){
            this.bmp=bitmap;
            this.x=x;
            this.y=y;
        }

        public Bitmap getBmp() {
            return bmp;
        }

        public void setBmp(Bitmap bmp) {
            this.bmp = bmp;
        }

        public int getX() {
            return x;
        }

        public void setX(int x) {
            this.x = x;
        }

        public int getY() {
            return y;
        }

        public void setY(int y) {
            this.y = y;
        }

        public boolean isTouched(){
            return touched;
        }

        public void setTouched(boolean touched){
            this.touched=touched;
        }

        public void draw(Canvas canvas){
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, x, y,null);
        }

        public void frogShiftRight(){
            this.x=this.x+20;

        }
        public void frogShiftLeft(){
            this.x=this.x-20;

        }
        public void frogShiftUp(){
            this.y=this.y-20;

        }
        public void frogShiftDown(){
            this.y=this.y+20;

        }
    }
```

And for the Vehicle class:

```
    public class Vehicle extends Thread implements Runnable{
        private Bitmap bmp;
        private static int x;
        private int y;
        Frog frog;
        Vehicle vehicle;

        public Vehicle(Bitmap bitmap,int x,int y){
            this.bmp=bitmap;
            this.x=x;
            this.y=y;
        }

        public Bitmap getBmp() {
            return bmp;
        }

        public void setBmp(Bitmap bmp) {
            this.bmp = bmp;
        }

        public int getX() {
            return x;
        }

        public void setX(int x) {
            this.x = x;
        }

        public int getY() {
            return y;
        }

        public void setY(int y) {
            this.y = y;
        }

        public void carmove(){
            try {
                x = x + 5;
                if(x>=300){
                    x=-50;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            setX(x);
        }

        public void collision(){
            if(frog.getX() <= x + getX() && frog.getY() <= y + getY()){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Collided", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        private Context getApplicationContext() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        public void draw(Canvas canvas){
            canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, x, y,null);
            carmove();
            collision();
        }
    }
```

Comment: any suggestions? this is my first game. So i have not much knowledge about it

Comment: Very unhelpful commenting. It is very specific : he wants to know the best approach to collision detection under Android. There may well be libraries and utilities in the Android framework to help. Two great examples of nothing to say but saying it anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I know what it is like about dealing with collision detection. If you want cheap advice here it is:
This will work with 2d games. Set each object a Rectangle for its boundries.
Set rectangle x and y as the top left positon and then the width the width of your object
set the height as the height of your object. Do the same thing with the other objects.

In the rectangle class there is a method called intersect or something like that. Do rect1.isIntersecting(rect2);
in the update method.
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

To check if two shapes are colliding, check axis one by one (X and Y axis in your case). You should make some research on this topic: "separate axis theorem". Here is a tutorial about it: http://www.metanetsoftware.com/technique/tutorialA.html (Section 1).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a rectangle collision check.  If (frogLeftvehicleLeft and frogTopvehicleTop) then you know they must be overlapping.  You could add methods for the top, right, left, bottom attributes to make the code pretty.

EX:

```
int right()
{
    return this.x+this.width;
}
```

Or you could make your objects inherit from java's rectangle2D.double object and use the built in intersection function: [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Rectangle2D.html#intersects(double, double, double, double)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Rectangle2D.html#intersects%28double,%20double,%20double,%20double%29) .

Also, I have a tutorial on 2D collision detection written in Java posted here: http://tylergriffin.me/collision_detection/

Answer (score 0):

if you are dealing with [rectangles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23774684/android-rect-intersect-is-always-false/23775232#23775232) then it may help you

```
/**
 * Check if two rectangles collide
 * x_1, y_1, width_1, and height_1 define the boundaries of the first rectangle
 * x_2, y_2, width_2, and height_2 define the boundaries of the second rectangle
 */
boolean rectangle_collision(float x_1, float y_1, float width_1, float height_1, float x_2, float y_2, float width_2, float height_2)
{
  return !(x_1 > x_2+width_2 || x_1+width_1 < x_2 || y_1 > y_2+height_2 || y_1+height_1 < y_2);
}
```