# Collision detection in 2D game in surfaceview

Tags: java, android

I want a collision between fruit & a weapon.Weapon will hit the fruit & fruit will be disappeared.I have to detect fruit boundary ,whenever weapon boundary find fruit boundary fruit should be disappeared.Fruits & weapons are populating through parsing using arrays.Fruit and weapon class extends from a class Sprite which have some common fields.There is another class in which line of equation.

DrawindPanel.java

class DrawingPannel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

```
PanelThread _thread;

public DrawingPannel(Context context, AttributeSet attrib) { 
    super(context, attrib); 
    getHolder().addCallback(this);
}
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    Sprite clickedSprrite = isItemClicked(event.getX(), event.getY());
    GameUtil.lastTaped = new Point((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY());

    ArrayList<Weapon> weapons = WeaponManager.weapons;

    for(int i = 0; i < weapons.size(); i++) {
        Weapon w = weapons.get(i);
        if(w.isSelected()) {
            w.setState(1);
        }

    }
```

return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

```
private Sprite isItemClicked(float x, float y) {
    //Checking if the tapped location has any item
    Sprite fruit;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < FruitManager.fruit.size(); i++) {
        fruit = FruitManager.fruit.get(i);
        float currentX = fruit.getCurrentX();
        float currentY = fruit.getCurrentY();
        float height = fruit.getCurrentBitmap().getHeight();
        float width = fruit.getCurrentBitmap().getWidth();

        if(x > currentX && x < currentX + width && y > currentY && y < currentY + height)
            return fruit;

    }
    return null;
}

public DrawingPannel(Context context) {
    super(context);
    getHolder().addCallback(this);
}

@Override 
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) { 
    Log.i("DrawingPannel", "onDraw");
    canvas.drawBitmap(GamePlayActivity.background.getCurrentBitmap(),0, 0, new Paint());
    UIObjectManager.getInstance().onDraw(canvas);

}
@Override 
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) { 


}
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {


    setWillNotDraw(false); //Allows us to use invalidate() to call onDraw()


    _thread = new PanelThread(getHolder(), this); //Start the thread that
    _thread.setRunning(true);                     //will make calls to 
    _thread.start();                              //onDraw()
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    try {
        //_thread.setRunning(false);                //Tells thread to stop
        _thread.join();                           //Removes thread from mem.
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
}
```

}

Comment: so where's the collision code?

Comment: I think that's exactly what he is missing, it's called "Collision detection", and here is a question related to it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227229/collision-detection-in-java-android?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

The simplest collision detection code works like this:

```
private void checkCollisions()
{
    GameObject go1 = null;
    GameObject go2 = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < gameObjects.size(); i++)
    {
        go1 = gameObjects.get(i);
        for (int j = i+1; j < gameObjects.size(); j++)
        {
            go2 = gameObjects.get(j);
            if (go1 != go2)
            {
                if (go1.checkCollision(go2))
                {
                    go1.interact(go2);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Where the collision in case of bounding circles is the following:

```
public boolean checkCollision(GameObject go)
{
    float distX = (go.getCalculatedX()-this.getCalculatedX());
    float distY = (go.getCalculatedY()-this.getCalculatedY());

    if((distX*distX + distY*distY)<= ((this.size+go.size)*(this.size+go.size)))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Where the simplest, non-Visitor pattern solution to interaction between objects is similar to the following:

```
@Override
public void interact(GameObject go)
{
    if ((owner instanceof Player && go instanceof Enemy) || (owner instanceof Enemy && go instanceof Player))
    {
        Unit u = (Unit) go;
        u.sufferDamage(this.damage);
        this.detachable = true;
        explode();
    }
}
```

Edit: An update function in which this type of collisionDetection would take place is the following:

```
public void updateWorld(float delta)
{
    for(float t = 0; t < delta; t += EPSILON)
    {
        float t_end = t + EPSILON;
        if(t_end > delta)
        {
            t_end = delta;
        }
        float dt = t_end - t;

        for(int i = 0; i < gameObjects.size(); i++)
        {
            gameObjects.get(i).update(dt);
        }

        /*for(int i = 0; i < gameObjects.size(); i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < gameObjects.size(); j++)
            {
                if(i != j)
                {
                    gameObjects.get(i).collidesWith(gameObjects.get(j));
                }
            }
        }*/

        checkCollisions();

        for(int i = 0; i < gameObjects.size(); i++)
        {
            if(gameObjects.get(i).isDetachable() == true)
            {
                gameObjects.remove(i--);
            }
        }

        timer -= dt;
        if(timer < 0)
        {
            onGameEnd();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Your case would be this:

```
private void checkCollisions()
{
    Weapon go1 = null;
    Fruit go2 = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < weapons.size(); i++)
    {
        go1 = weapons.get(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < fruits.size(); j++)
        {
            go2 = fruits.get(j);
            if (go1 != go2)
            {
                if (go1.checkCollision(go2))
                {
                    go1.interact(go2);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the Weapon would have the function at which it interacts with the Fruit. Assuming the lack of common superclass here.

Comment: as i told u i dnt want to remove fruit by tapping on screen.Where i tap on the screen weapon comes to that point and disappeared.& weapon is moving correctly just to remove the fruit by weapon

Comment: No, this is in an "update" function where you refresh the world. I'll edit that into the answer as well.

Comment: the two objects which u wrote "Game Object (go1& go2)".r they like my fruit & weapon objects ????

Comment: If they have a common superclass, then yes.

I guess if you have a list for each weapon, and a list for each fruit seperately, then you can just iterate through those in this fashion and check collision like that.

Comment: Added a specific case for you.

Comment: error on this line 
if (go1 != go2).... and the error is "incompatible operands type weapon and fruit"

Comment: You are right. Remove that line and it will wotk prrfectly fine.

Comment: It should not, considering in your case, you are iterating on two different arrays, and the objects can never match. The error is elsewhere.

Comment: I have to get only fruit array. & i just have to use weapon(x,y) & getters methods for weapon coordinates r already in a superclass.i just want to remove fruits by comparing/detecting with weapon coordinates. Plz Help me i thnk u can help me to some extent u got me what i am trying to do

Comment: How do you keep track of the existing weapons? Are there multiple weapons, or only one? You need to check if there are any weapons that are overlapping (colliding with) any of the fruit.

Comment: there is only one weapon in one level

Comment: That's neat. That means you just need to iterate the Fruit's array, check the collision with that single weapon, and if it's true, then remove the fruit from the list and do what else needs to be done.

Comment: thats i m trying to do but ant understand what to do to achieve ths can u plz check this out????

Comment: If there is any way to see the full source in a simple manner, then sure.